# Move a Dropbox subfolder

Tags: hard-drive, sync, dropbox

Here is my situation: I have a 1 To Dropbox account. So far, I use it to access to some documents I modified frequently from my laptop.

These documents leave me a lot of space on the account, so I was considering to add the photos I have on an external hard drive (about 100 Go).

My problem: my laptop's storage capacity is insufficient to just add the pictures in the Dropbox folder. Adding the picture by drag-and-drop on the Internet interface takes a lot of time and often, I need to go offline before everything is uploaded. And of course, this does not sync the pictures as I add them to the external hard drive. The hard drive is not always connected to my laptop: I want to add the pictures when I take some and then sync them to DropBox.

**My question**: is there a simple way a "split" a Dropbox folder, one part on my laptop and the other one on the external hard drive for the pictures?

If my external hard drive were a computer, I could just install the Dropbox apps on it and sync only the pictures, and sync everything but the pictures on the laptop.

Edit: I am using Windows 10 if it matters for the question.

Comment: You cannot split a folder per se.  But you can dow load the dropbox app that integrates into windows and work with that from windows file explorer.  It will try to sync the "dropbox folder" on you computer all the time and seamlessly.

Comment: Not a solution to your question, but an alternative to consider, which is *Google Drive*.  You can purchase a 1TB account for relatively cheap, and its *Backup & Sync* app is good for two reasons: 1. It permits multiple accounts to use the same device, unlike *Dropbox*; 2. It only needs a single account to achieve what you need, which is to choose different locations across your drive(s) to be sync'd to *Drive*.  Additionally, picture and video storage is free and unlimited.

Comment: @CJK: that's a good idea but I am already paying for a Dropbox account.